# Do oauth2 flow enpoint also perform the health check of google action?

Tags: google-oauth, actions-on-google, health-check, actions-builder

I have followed the requirements of [Health Checks](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/health-checks) to return 200 code in my webhook endpiont, but it still shows unhealthy.

Does my OAuth2 endpoint also need to be implemented? If so, how? Since doing so would break the OAuth2 standard.

My service uses Google Actions Builder .

Comment: The short answer is no, you don't. But you don't show your code or any logs associated with your webhook. You may wish to update your question with your code and any logs that are generated when calling your webhook. The more info you can provide, the better chance we can help solve the problem. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: here is my [endpoint](https://api-ca.midea.com/v1/google/vrobot) , you can check with health check request. { "handler": { "name": "actions.handler.HEALTH_CHECK" }, "intent": { "name": "actions.intent.HEALTH_CHECK" }, "session": { "id": "actions.session.HEALTH_CHECK" }, "user": { "locale":"en-US" }, "device": { "capabilities": [] } }

Comment: please update your *question* with any additional information and then comment you've done so. Trying to add code to the comments make it very difficult to read. That looks like the Request you're getting from the Assistant, however, not your code about how you are handling it.

Comment: ok,  here is my [webhook endpoint](https://api-ca.midea.com/v1/google/myblink) ,Please help me to test whether I have any problems with the handling of the health check. Besides the need to reply response 200 code, are there any additional requirements for the response body?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to do anything special on your OAuth endpoint. (It has to work, of course, but it isn't tested by the health checker.)

There are many reasons why your webhook may be judged as "unhealthy", even if you think you're handling it correctly. The most likely, of course, is that you're not - you may be throwing an error when you don't think you are. If you are not handling the health check specifically, you may also be using features that the health checker does not "support" (for example, sending back a Media response).

Checking logs, both for your webhook and in Cloudwatch for the Assistant, may help you narrow your problem down. If you update your question, we may be able to provide additional guidance.

Comment: here is my [endpoint](https://api-ca.midea.com/v1/google/vrobot) , you can check with health check request.  {
  "handler": {
    "name": "actions.handler.HEALTH_CHECK"
  },
  "intent": {
    "name": "actions.intent.HEALTH_CHECK"
  },
  "session": {
    "id": "actions.session.HEALTH_CHECK"
  },
  "user": {
    "locale":"en-US"
  },
  "device": {
    "capabilities": []
  }
}